# Smoke stopper circuit

Tags: circuit-design

I've built a [smoke stopper](https://oscarliang.com/smoke-stopper/) circuit that I want to use once my first quadcopter will be built. It's basically a simple circuit that sits between the LiPo battery and the drone, that lights a lamp if a short happens on the quad's end.

I've slightly modified the circuit from what is visible at the link above. A second switch (Hi) includes the higher power lamp.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fO65Zp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have two questions in regards:

1. Is the indicator LED correctly placed? I tried the circuit without it and it works as intended. I wanted a confirmation on this part. The LED should light up if I connect the battery and the "Power" switch is ON, so I can have a visual feedback.
2. What if I want to use a DPDT switch (momentary type, ON-OFF-ON), as a test for the lamps? Without attaching the drone, I would use it to test the two lamps, based on the side I engage. Is it possible at all?

[image]

Comment: Please add the DPDT switch to your schematic to show where you intend to add it. Also, is the resistor really 10 kilohm?

Comment: Well I don't know where to add the switch. I only thought that would be cool to test the lamps before seeing if they actually light up due to a short. I have this switch and I thought to use it, one side per lamp. If it's possible. Yes sorry the R is 1k: I tried the LED I want to use with it under 12V. It still gives a sufficiently bright light.

Comment: The problem with testing the lamps is that you'd need to know a suitable current.  Too little and they just get warm, then a medium range where they get warm enough to glow visibly, and then one where they act as fuses.  If you know the voltage the lamps are intended for, then applying that across them could work.

Comment: So why are you asking about a DPDT switch? Is that just what you happen to have on hand?

Comment: @ChrisStratton I know my LiPo it's 2200mAh (65C) and around 12V (depending on the charge level). Lamps are automotive ones at 12V, 20W and 8W.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Yes is what I have. I thought it fitted exactly because it's DPDT

Comment: All you need is a PTC in series and a LED+R across output https://www.digikey.ca/en/product-highlight/b/bel-fuse/ptc-resettable-fuses. Cheap so get a variety of holding currents.

Comment: Presumably the motivation arrises from the fact that you can walk into an auto parts store and buy a signal bulb, while a PTC has to be ordered from an electronics vendor.  Also, the later is not self-indicating, while for some range of currents the former is.

Comment: Yes but also I like the bulky grey ABS project box with all the switches sticking outside, the indicator LED and the transparent window with the two bulbs inside. :)

Comment: You could test the smoke stopper out by shorting out the battery connected to the smoke stopper. If it's connected correctly, the battery should now be shorted to the lamp (totally normal). Just make sure you have a quick way to separate the wires if it wasn't connected correctly. Sometimes the wires weld together because of the high current.

Comment: @hatsunearu yes this is how I tested the thing. I also used a 12V power supply, instead of a battery, just to be safe (not to burn a battery... you know...). I think I'll use a simple SPST momentary switch to test the lamps, and use the hi-low switch to test one or both... so I'll consider this Q as answered. I'm trying now. If it works, I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I used a simple SPST momentary bush-button to test the lamps, with the hi-low switch to test one or both lamps.
[image: Circuit]
[image]